# How to exclude/skip items from sorting?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

There is an array of objects, which I need to be sorted. It looks like this:

```
var array = [
    {left: 20, top: 50, group: 'groupOne'},
    {left: 18, top: 10, group: 'groupTwo'},
    {left: 15, top: 15, group: 'groupThree'},
    {left: 25, top: 30, group: 'groupThree'},
    {left: 18, top: 25, group: 'groupFour'},
    {left: 28, top: 25, group: 'groupFive'},
    {left: 25, top: 15, group: 'groupSix'},
    {left: 30, top: 30, group: 'groupSix'}
];
```

I want to sort it by **left** (primarily) and **top** (secondly). My sort function looks like this:

```
array.sort((x, y) => {
    return x.left - y.left || x.top - y.top;
});
```

The result is:

```
[
    {left: 15, top: 15, group: "groupThree"},
    {left: 18, top: 10, group: "groupTwo"},
    {left: 18, top: 25, group: "groupFour"},
    {left: 20, top: 50, group: "groupOne"},
    {left: 25, top: 15, group: "groupSix"},
    {left: 25, top: 30, group: "groupThree"},
    {left: 28, top: 25, group: "groupFive"},
    {left: 30, top: 30, group: "groupSix"}
];
```

Sorting fuction works almost exactly how I wanted, but it would be better if it also consider the **group** if there is more than one item of the same group.

In other words I want final result to look like below:

```
[
    {left: 15, top: 15, group: "groupThree"},
    {left: 25, top: 30, group: "groupThree"},
    {left: 18, top: 10, group: "groupTwo"},
    {left: 18, top: 25, group: "groupFour"},
    {left: 20, top: 50, group: "groupOne"},
    {left: 25, top: 15, group: "groupSix"},
    {left: 30, top: 30, group: "groupSix"}
    {left: 28, top: 25, group: "groupFive"},
];
```

Items from the same group "stick" together.
Any ideas?

Comment: Just put a `.localeCompare()` for the group between the comparisons for `left` and `top`. It's the same as what you're already doing, in other words.

Comment: And how do two groups get sorted? Based on the first one of a group?

Comment: If two items has the same group, they should be sorted in the same way as before (left and top).

Comment: Pointy, what do you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could group the items and sort the grouped items and then sort by the first element of the grouped item.

Later flat all groups.

```js
var array = [{ left: 20, top: 50, group: 'groupOne' }, { left: 18, top: 10, group: 'groupTwo' }, { left: 15, top: 15, group: 'groupThree' }, { left: 25, top: 30, group: 'groupThree' }, { left: 18, top: 25, group: 'groupFour' }, { left: 28, top: 25, group: 'groupFive' }, { left: 25, top: 15, group: 'groupSix' }, { left: 30, top: 30, group: 'groupSix' }],
    leftTop = (a, b) => a.left - b.left || a.top - b.top,
    sorted = Array
        .from(
            array
                .reduce((m, o) => m.set(o.group, (m.get(o.group) || []).concat(o)), new Map)
                .values(),
            a => a.sort(leftTop)
        )
        .sort(([a], [b]) => leftTop(a, b))
        .reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b));

console.log(sorted);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks Nina, the solution is perfect for me. But can you tell me one more thing?
While debugging the code I stopped at `.sort(([x], [y]) => leftTop(x, y))` part (I just changed letters). I know browser sometimes somehow transform the code to read it in other way, but why it changed it to `.sort(function(_a, _b) { var x = _a[0]; var y = _b[0]; return... })`. How the browser knew it shoud take only first element of array? In other words, how `[x]` changed to `_a[0]`

Comment: it is part of a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), where an array is destructured into an array ans the first item is taken. the browser know it by syntax of ES6.