# Array as parameter in sort's callback function

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, parameters, arguments

This question is linked to one I wrote a few days ago. I received the answer, it worked, but there is a thing I don't understand. Here is a link: [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53683359/how-to-exclude-skip-items-from-sorting)

While debugging the code I stopped at `.sort(([x], [y]) => leftTop(x, y))` part (I just changed letters). I know browser sometimes somehow transform the code to read it in other way, but why it changed it to `.sort(function(_a, _b) { var x = _a[0]; var y = _b[0]; return... })`? In other words, how `[x]` changed to `_a[0]`?

Comment: Looks like something Babel would do - transform ES6+ syntax into ES5 compatible syntax (the logic is the same), though hard to say for certain without seeing what exactly your setup is. (it's not something the *browser* would do, I would think, it's something your *build process* would do)

Answer (score 0):

#### Short answer

ES6 → ES5 transpilation

#### Longer answer

The syntax `([x], [y]) => leftTop(x, y)` is an [arrow function](http://es6-features.org/#ExpressionBodies), which is a way to express a function that didn't existed in EcmaScript2009 (aka ES5), but exists in EcmaScript2015 (aka ES6) and later.

There are many reasons why people would transpile their code from ES6 to ES5, mainly to ensure compatibility with browsers and tools.

It is so frequent that many tools use ES6→ES5 transpilation by default, like [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) or [ng new](https://cli.angular.io/). Under the hood, the most widely used transpilation tool is [babel](https://babeljs.io/). It is very likely that you're using it while building your application, thus the changes in your syntax.

Comment: It is definitely NOT what I meant, but I got the response in the thread I linked.